# How to create a read only text box

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I need to create a text box that the user can't change the value of.

Also I would like the text box to display the value of another combo box and update when that combo box's selected item changes

Please help me.

Comment: Set ReadOnly = true

Comment: Please Don't Write In Title Case.

Comment: Tidy up casing and wording to make it clear what the user was asking

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Text Box and in the Properties Tab change the value of ReadOnly to “True”

Answer (score 0):

TextBox.ReadOnly = true; should do the trick